# Floating div using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want a floating div to the right side of the content, I have one script in my hand but shows the div in left side, how to chnage the div position to right by editing the following script.

here is the script..

```
//avoid conflict with other script
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function($) {

//this is the floating content
var $floatingbox = $('#floating-box');

if($('#body').length > 0){

  var bodyY = parseInt($('#body').offset().top) - 20;
  var originalX = $floatingbox.css('margin-left');

  $(window).scroll(function () { 

   var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
   var isfixed = $floatingbox.css('position') == 'fixed';

   if($floatingbox.length > 0){

      //$floatingbox.html("srollY : " + scrollY + ", bodyY : " 
                                //+ bodyY + ", isfixed : " + isfixed);

      if ( scrollY > bodyY && !isfixed ) {
        $floatingbox.stop().css({
          position: 'fixed',
          left: '50%',
          top: 20,
          marginLeft: -500
        });
    } else if ( scrollY < bodyY && isfixed ) {
          $floatingbox.css({
          position: 'relative',
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          marginLeft: originalX
    });
     }      
   }
   });
 }
});
```

I'm looking forward to the replies..

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you need a script to do this? It seems to me that it would be easily done with straight CSS declarations:

```
.floatingdiv {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:20px; // or whatever
}
```

Now, I know that fixed positioning isn't supported in IE6, but you can at least use a hack to have IE6 fall back to position:absolute. There are several suggestions around, but I like this one. Add the following (including the asterisk) to your stylesheet after your initial style declaration for the element:

```
* html .floatingdiv { 
    position: absolute;
}
```

You don't get the fixed effect in IE6, but the trade-off is that you get a performance boost because you don't need the extra javascript to load. In anything since IE7 you also get a smoother performance for that fixed div.

Comment: but Scott I think you didnt get me. Actually I want a functioning like  http://mashable.com/2010/11/03/facebook-deals-platform/ the left side floting widget so JQuery is must for working in that style..

Comment: You would only need jQuery if you want the widget to delay its movement a bit (slide to the top before following the browser window down the page) like on mashable.com. If you're willing to let the widget move as soon as the user scrolls at all, then CSS will do it.

Comment: If what you're worried about is flexible horizontal layout, you can just specify the left-margin of the widget as a percentage.